# What hikes are must-do at the Grand Canyon north rim?

Tags: hiking, united-states

My wife and I are going to the north rim in April and May. We would like to do several hikes, hopefully ones that let us experience the best of the Grand Canyon's north rim. We are interested in hikes of various lengths and difficulties.

Comment: I'd like to know this too. Its always been a long term goal to go to the Grand canyon.

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on what sort of condition you're in.  For example, if you're a trail-runner in good shape who's used to high altitudes, the 28 miles from the rim to Phantom Ranch and back would be a reasonable day trip; if you're a sedentary lowlander, even a flat one-mile hike might be hard.

The National Park Service has a list of [North Rim trails](http://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/day-hiking.htm#CP_JUMP_103529).  If you want to go down into the canyon, there's really only one choice: the North Kaibab Trail.  You can follow it to Coconino Overlook, Supai Tunnel, or Roaring Springs in a day depending on your level of fitness (rule of thumb: hiking out takes twice as long as hiking in).  For views from the canyon rim, there are various trails ranging from the half-mile Bright Angel Point trail to the ten-mile Ken Patrick trail: pick one (or more).

Comment: thanks Mark. Leaving tomorrow. Probably going to just go down to Supai tunnel and back up. And then do a lot of the shorter/easier hikes to the different viewpoints. Are the well-known hikes (like Uncle Jims and Ken Patrick) on well-marked trails? I haven't been able to find waypoints for GPS so hoping that's the case.

Comment: Yes, the trails are generally well-marked and well-maintained.